# Crash (sometimes) from a native method

Tags: java, javafx, dll, jna

I have to use a device with a JavaFX GUI. The communication with the device is made with native methods (propietary methods, so I cannot deep into dll's code). When I run it on a simple screen, it works fine, but I want to initialize it from another JavaFx screen, there comes crash dump `hs_err_pidxxxx.log` style.
Basically, I launch first the GUI of initialization of my device, and if it works properly (all the time!) I acceed to the window that will use the device.

```
    DeviceInitializer initializer = new DeviceInitializer();
    initializer.showAndWait();
    if (initializer.isRequiredDeviceInitialized()) {
        stage.show();
    }
```

in my `DeviceInitializer` controller I initialize the device with the initialization method from dll. and put it in a static objects:

```
private static Device instance;
public static Device getDevice() {
   instance= Objects.isNull(instance) ? new Device() : instance;
    return instance;
}
```

From there, I use my `instance` to interact with device but there appears an undeterministic behaviour (sometimes it crashes, sometimes no...)

```
2018-07-18 11:55:14,664 [JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG Device- Invalid memory access
java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
```

Comment: It may have to do with `showAndWait()`. There are some issues with nested event loops. Try it with `show()` if you do not absolutely require `showAndWait()`.

Comment: So it really was that `showAndWait()` problem? If so, I'd recommend submitting a bug report for this. There are already several bug reports on `showAndWait()`, but there isn't any relating to JNA. It would be good for them to test the fix thoroughly.

Comment: I bypassed it in my code (I had to find a trick cause I needed `showAndWait()`, So i'mnt really sure the crash comes from that.